# using TwigTrait in silex

Tags: php, twig, silex

I'm using silex for one of my projects and usually when  i want render a twig template I use this syntax :

```
$app['twig']->render('page.twig');
```

in this project I want to use the trait to have this syntax :

```
$app->render('page.twig');
```

to do that I modified the Application class in Silex\Application and added :

```
use TwigTrait;
```

so my question is : if its ok to do that and modify this class or if not, is there another way to do that.

thanks in advance and I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Whatever class you use the trait in, gets the `render()` method. Are you sure you don't mean `$this->render('page.twig');` ?

Comment: i already did that in my pagesController like that :

`public function indexAction() {
        return $this->render('pages/index.twig');
 }`

but i have this exception :
**FatalErrorException in TwigTrait.php line 37:
Error: Cannot use object of type \MyNameSpace\Controller\PagesController as array **

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the class, just extend it. The Silex test suite [has an example](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/6ca8bf8815d00e307bc928b22948ff7e6e1ef850/tests/Silex/Tests/Application/TwigApplication.php). Then just use it like you would the normal application class.

```
$app = new MyTwigApp();
```